# How sum values in a hash inside another hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a problem, I'm using hash for my app, this hash collect and should to sum some datas.

```
def os_versions
  @hash_os_versions = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
  for user in @users do
    for os_version in user.profile.os_versions do
      unless @hash_os_versions.key?(os_version.operating_system_id.to_s)
        @hash_os_versions[os_version.operating_system_id.to_s][os_version.name] = 0
      end
        @hash_os_versions.values.inject(0){|h,k| k[os_version.name] = 1}
    end
  end
  @hash_os_versions
end
```

This hash results:

{"1"=>{"Fedora"=>1, "OS X 10.4 Tiger"=>1, "OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard"=>1, "Windows 2000"=>1, "Debian"=>1, "OpenSUSE"=>1, "OS X 10.5 Leopard"=>1, "OS X 10.7 Lion"=>1, "Red Hat"=>1, "Ubuntu"=>1, "Windows 7"=>1, "Windows 98"=>1, "Windows Vista"=>1, "Windows XP"=>1}, "2"=>{"OS X 10.4 Tiger"=>1, "OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard"=>1, "Windows 2000"=>1, "Debian"=>1, "Fedora"=>1, "OpenSUSE"=>1, "OS X 10.5 Leopard"=>1, "OS X 10.7 Lion"=>1, "Red Hat"=>1, "Ubuntu"=>1, "Windows 7"=>1, "Windows 98"=>1, "Windows Vista"=>1, "Windows XP"=>1}, ...}

Basically:
id_operation_system => os_version_name => count

But, I can't to sum the values, I tried:

```
@hash_os_versions.values.inject(0){|h,k| k[os_version.name] += 1}
```

But return an error:

```
undefined method `+' for {}:Hash
```

I know I need to use inject, but it's not working.

Ps: Please, sorry my english

Comment: how do you want to add these values that comes in hash ?

Comment: I want make a counter, each interaction I check if the enter exists, if yes, I increment the counter inside hash.